# Video Player for RN

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront

I am planning to create an OTT platform and I'm currently using AWS S3 and CloudFront as my CDN. I attempted to install React-Native-Video-Player, but it seems that it is no longer available in React Native.

So,  Are there any video players that support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using: [React-Native-Video](https://react-native-video.github.io/react-native-video/).

Currently, React-Native-Video-Player is not actively maintained.